# Sending POST Requests using Postman(Chrome plugin), but receiving GET request-why?

Tags: jax-rs, websphere, postman, websphere-liberty

I'm sending a POST request via POSTMAN, but my server (WebServer) is receiving it as a GET request - can anyone think why this can happen? Here is some info from postman (part of the URL/hostnames annonymised):

```
POST /blaa/DescriptionEntities/description HTTP/1.1
Host: blaaa
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3901995b-78a0-598f-40d2-83b09e09d12e
id=20&description=hi
```

The code:

```
@POST
@Path("description")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public DescriptionEntity      createDescriptionEntity(MultivaluedMap<String,String>map){


    System.out.println(map.getFirst("id"));
    System.out.println(map.getFirst("description"));
    return null;

}
```

The  Server (WebSphere):

```
 No operation matching request path "/blaa/DescriptionEntities/description"      is found, Relative Path: /description, HTTP Method: GET, ContentType: */*, Accept: */*,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details-is anyone able to kindly help here.
```

Not sure how to set the log level here either(I'm new to this).The relative path at the class level is "DescriptionEntities" Thanks so much.

EDIT- this is the whole class (minus import statements-it's completely experimental and ignore non related errors):

```
   @Path("DescriptionEntities")
   public class DescriptionEntityResource {
   private DescriptionEntityRepository descriptionEntityRepository=new       DescriptionEntityRepository();
    @Path("description")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
   public DescriptionEntity createDescriptionEntity(MultivaluedMap<String,String>map){


    System.out.println(map.getFirst("id"));
    System.out.println(map.getFirst("description"));
    return null;

}
```

}

And the URL in Postman:  http://blaa/DescriptionEntities/Description

EDIT: Server.xml

```
  <server description="new server">
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>json-1.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.1</feature>
    <feature>jsf-2.2</feature>
    <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
</featureManager>

<httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="80" httpsPort="443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint" sslOptionsRef="endpointSSLOptions"/> 
<sslOptions id="endpointSSLOptions" sslRef="endpointSSL"/>
<ssl enabledCiphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 " id="endpointSSL" keyStoreRef="customKeyStore"/>
<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="annonymised"/>
<basicRegistry/>

<mimeTypes>
    <type>svg=image/svg+xml</type>
</mimeTypes>

<httpSession useContextRootAsCookiePath="true" cookieSecure="true" />
<logging consoleLogLevel="INFO"/>
<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>

<webApplication id="annonymised" location="annonymised" name="annonymised"/>
```

EDIT:  Network traffic (using fiddler):

```
POST /blaa/DescriptionEntities/description HTTP/1.1
Host: blaa
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 20
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Accept: */*
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

EDIT: The GET request:

```
 GET /blaa/DescriptionEntities/description HTTP/1.1
 Host: blaa
 Connection: keep-alive
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
 Accept: */*
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: IBMISP=b645ef125eca11e6aeed1341c031a83e-   b645ef125eca11e6aeed1341c031a83e-0801740c1b0bc161a63c23e998bba6ec; CoreM_State=83~-1~-1~-1~-1~3~3~5~3~3~7~7~|~~|~~|~~|~||||||~|~~|~~|~~|~~|~~|~~|~~|~; CoreM_State_Content=6~|~~|~|; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1470813611355r0.3187708418093793; ajs_user_id=null; ajs_group_id=null; amplitude_idibm.com=eyJkZXZpY2VJZCI6Ijk0ZGZlZWE0LTg4NjEtNDMzNi04Yzk5LWMyZWMwNjMxOGZmNFIiLCJ1c2VySWQiOm51bGwsIm9wdE91dCI6ZmFsc2UsInNlc3Npb25JZCI6MTQ3MDgxMzY4MDQ4MCwibGFzdEV2ZW50VGltZSI6MTQ3MDgxMzY4MDQ5MCwiZXZlbnRJZCI6MSwiaWRlbnRpZnlJZCI6MSwic2VxdWVuY2VOdW1iZXIiOjJ9; ajs_anonymous_id=%22b645ef125eca11e6aeed1341c031a83e%22; intercom-id=19922b40-fb41-4744-9dfb-89d6875c0294; UnicaNIODID=enSkfJ02Gh7-Z3dNjvn; optimizelySegments=%7B%222753990332%22%3A%22gc%22%2C%222757810742%22%3A%22search%22%2C%222762380326%22%3A%22false%22%2C%223081321317%22%3A%22none%22%2C%223855873690%22%3A%22referral%22%2C%223859505928%22%3A%22none%22%2C%223860673668%22%3A%22gc%22%2C%223861195110%22%3A%22false%22%7D; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D; cvo_sid1=EEHN9V3GC6UB; cvo_tid1=BF-jgeF2_Y4|1470813613|1471260957|0; mmcore.tst=0.794; mmapi.store.p.0=%7B%22mmparams.d%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22mmparams.p%22%3A%7B%22mmid%22%3A%221502797170504%7C%5C%22716298243%7CCgAAAApStaCTtQ0AAA%3D%3D%5C%22%22%2C%22pd%22%3A%221502797170506%7C%5C%22-1893569528%7CCgAAAAoBQlK1oJO1DfyoSkgDAOpF09EAxdNIDwAAABoXwicJwdNIAAAAAP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FAAZEaXJlY3QBtQ0DAAAAAAAAAAAAAP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwAAAAAAAUU%3D%5C%22%22%2C%22srv%22%3A%221502797170510%7C%5C%22ldnvwcgus01%5C%22%22%7D%7D; __auc=f59597cf1567352a7c8a1f92cde; _ga=GA1.2.1447575942.1471939647; CoreID6=67988125510914708136127&ci=50200000|Bluemix_51040000|IBMTESTW3_51040000|HR_50200000|IBM_GlobalMarketing_50200000|devwrkscon_50200000|ESTKCS_50200000|DWNEXT; utag_main=v_id:01567352a47a000fc70d49709b1a04072002b06a00718$_sn:4$_ss:0$_st:1471941446924$dc_visit:4$_pn:7%3Bexp-session$ses_id:1471937020076%3Bexp-session$dc_event:19%3Bexp-session$dc_region:eu-central-1%3Bexp-session$ttd_uuid:f57e787f-a10b-48bc-833c-add2cf0e063d%3Bexp-session; 50200000_clogin=v=1&l=1471937020&e=1471941448777
```

EDIT: I have purged this little test project for now as I can't figure out what's wrong. I may try another time a little further down the line. Still curious as to what went wrong though so let me know if you spot anything obvious. Thanks everyone

Comment: I'm getting a status 302 when turning on the interceptor in Postman....can anyone tell me why the redeirect is being attempted?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian as far as I understand, if the interceptor is turned off (interceptor prevents redirection) it's just attempting a GET request to that same URL, so instead of performing the POST, it's attempting to perform a GET and then failing as there is no such GET request. Any leads will be greatly appreciated-thanks!

Comment: The only thing I was thinking was that if the page requires authentication and none was provided. That could trigger a redirect, but usually not to the same page though.

Comment: @DanielBarbarian Do you have any fellow WebSphere/JAXRS experts you could ask? This one is starting to annoy me now :)

Comment: Enable developer tools and capture the network requests. Something is causing a redirect, which of course causes a GET. The 302 redirect response will have a Location header. Look at your WebSphere logs as well. And what version of WebSphere?

Comment: I meant your browser developer tools. F12. You can watch the network requests there. Like your Fiddler output, but from just the base browser. Your Fiddler output shows only a single request, and no response. Do you have the response also? And clearly a GET was sent at some point.

Comment: (I'm also assuming your `/blaa` in the first example and `/annonymised` in the second one are your web application's context root?)

Comment: @dbreux Yes. Added the get request. I've noticed that the get request is coming through as HTTPS an the 302 as HTTP. Could it be a Postman config thing? Really confused here. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No, but an equivalent GET to same URL works. Will be back at this tomorrow morning (time for me to leave work now). Thanks very much

Comment: Is anything sitting in between postman and your web server? A proxy, Internet gateway, security device, etc.? Try to debug locally if you can.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem due to the fact that I sent GET and POST requests to the same route, the only thing was that the POST request was with the int:registration_pk parameter
What helped me was switching the parameter in the settings:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt3IP.png)

Comment: What would ask for the redirect though - can you elaborate on that?